# gcc inline assembly: What is the difference between output and output-only?

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, inline-assembly

The following assembly works (in `-O2`) if all of my outputs are "output-only" (`=&`), but not if they are "output" (`=`). What is the difference between these two modes, and how can the behavior of the program change *when the assembly is not reading the register?*

```
  __asm (
     "ldrb %[H], %[P0] \n"                 // P[0]
     "ldrb %[L], %[P4] \n"                 // P[4]
     "add %[H], %[Htbl], %[H], lsl #4 \n"  // H = Htbl + P[0]
     "add %[L], %[Htbl], %[L], lsl #4 \n"  // L = Htbl + P[4]
     "mov %[S], %[Z0], LSL #24 \n"         // S = Z0 << 24
     :
     [H]   "=&r" (H),
     [L]   "=&r" (L),
     [S]   "=&r" (S),
     [tmp] "=&r" (tmp)
     :
     [Z0]   "r" (Z0),
     [Htbl] "r" (Htbl),
     [P0]   "m" (P[0]),
     [P4]   "m" (P[4])
     );
```

Comment: The `&` prohibits the compiler from using the register for an input operand as well. It doesn't matter whether your code reads the original operand - in fact it should not, because it's an output in either case. For example, the input `Z0` may use the same register as output `H`. Clearly that will break the code since the very first thing you do is change `H` thereby destroying the input `Z0`. This is why you need to use the `&` early clobber.

Comment: Reading the output of `gcc -O2 -S` is likely to bring enlightenment.

Comment: @Jester Well that would explain the problem I was having with "=". So then "=" is only useful if your assembly code first captures all of its inputs before clobbering anything? E.g., if it's just a single instruction?

Comment: Or if the constraints won't allow a collision anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing "=&" described as "output-only."  Looking at the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html), I see "&" referred to as "earlyclobber," which seems to better describe what it does.

Comment: Well, "output only" also makes sense if you consider that the compiler is not allowed to use the same thing for an input as well.